# Encoding a nested object that does not have nested property in its model

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding, codable

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct Event: Codable {
    var id: Int
    .... // many non nested fields
}
```

In my application a user is allowed to create a list of events. Once the user is finished I'd like to pass that list to my server via a POST request.

In order to do so I need to create a valid JSON object that looks like this.
This is a list of `Event` with a leading key of `"events"`.

```
{ "events": [{"id": 1, ... more of the non nested fields ... },{ ... }]}
```

How can I setup my `Event` object in such a way that `JSONEncoder.encode(events)` will return the expected JSON above? I would really like to avoid having a CodingKey for each field because they encode,decode just fine expect in this circumstance. I'd also like to avoid nesting this `Event` object inside another struct called `Events` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just encode a dictionary which associates your `events` array to the key `"events"`

```
JSONEncoder.encode(["events": events])
```